# Fix appereance of a Codename One lightweight date picker

Tags: codenameone

The same Codename One lightweight picker appears in the following two ways (the difference is "01/01/00" on Android and "01/01/2000" on iPhone).

**Android**
[image: cod]

**iPhone**
[image]

I need to fix two issues about the appearance. The first one is the date: "01/01/00" is bad, "01/01/2000" is better, "1 gennaio 2000" (localized in Italian) is what I prefer on both OSes.

The second one is internal layout of the picker: on the iPhone screenshot you can see that the date selector is not centered, but aligned on the left. It's better if it's aligned on the center on both OSes. The same issue is on Android, but it's less visible (in this case).

Comment: Please don't add screen shot. Add code here. That would help others to debug and provide answer.

Comment: Did you downvote because that? The code for a Codename One lightweight picker is trivial for both screenshots, that's why I didn't add it. It's something like: `Picker datePicker = new Picker();
                            datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
                            datePicker.setUseLightweightPopup(true);`

Comment: are you using the localization manager?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

Comment: Thank you, but `SimpleDateFormat` is deprecated: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html About the localization manager, I'm using the default localization provided by Codename One. This is the API of the Picker I'm using, there is no mention of how to localize the date shown by the picker: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/spinner/Picker.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date formatting can be customized using:

```
 picker.setFormatter(mySimpleDateFormat);
```

This should allow you to explicitly define a formatting. The default is to use your device settings which explains the difference between them.

Notice that you should use `com.codename1.l10n.SimpleDateFormat` not the `java.text` version.

About centering, I'm not sure if it's possible. This was also a pain on the native picker in iOS. You can file an RFE about that and we can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another chance is something like the following, for the maximum customization:

```
Picker value = new Picker() {
    @Override
    protected void updateValue() {
        if (getDate() == null) {
            setText(" ");
            return;
        }
        setText(L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateLongStyle(getDate()));
    }
};
```